# explain behind the scenes of make in golang?

Tags: go

What is the difference between the following?

1. `cards := deck{}`
2. `cards := make(deck, 52)`
3. `cards := make(deck, 0, 52)`

where, deck is an array of strings representing cards `type deck []string`.

Now, the issue that I am facing is that when I run the following `print()` function on a deck of cards using `cards:= make(deck, 52)`, I see that it prints 52 empty lines before printing the cards in the deck however, when using `1` or `3` from above it works completely fine printing only the 52 cards of the deck.

```
func (d deck) print()  {
    for _, card := range d {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf(`%s`, card))
    }
}
```

I don't get this, am I missing anything? Thanks!

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types and https://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels

Comment: You're missing the distinction between size and capacity of slices. https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cards := deck{}` This creates an empty deck.

`cards:= make(deck, 52)` This creates a deck containing 52 empty elements

`cards:= make(deck, 0, 52)` This creates an empty deck with a capacity of 52. That is, you can append to `cards` 52 items before a new allocation is required.